# Add ASP.NET_SessionId to jQuery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, session-cookies

I merged an ASP.NET and a HTML/jQuery projects.
The ASP.NET project uses a session id but it does not show up in my background requests.
I see the "ASP.NET_SessionId" among browser cookies, but it is inaccessible by JS.
How can I tell the browser to use the "ASP.NET_SessionId" when connecting to the server?
Can I set it through the $.post() function?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with it, you shouldn't expose it to js as then you are vulnerable to session hijacking

Comment: I post and get (user-specific) data (of logged-in user) through AJAX in the background. I see the session ID in the browser URL, but it is missing from the AJAX requests.

Comment: and what are you calling by Ajax? a webservice? HttpHandler? webform?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the session cookie because it is set to HTTP Only.

so it is hidden from JavaScript for security reasons. It would be a massive security flaw to expose it to JavaScript.

[Please Read this Blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I do not want to access the session ID by JS. I tought, that XHRs are performed by the browser. I just want to tell the browser to use the session ID that the browser stores.

Comment: in ASP.NET or MVC ?

Comment: I think it is ASP.NET. Made with VS2010.

Comment: The session cookie is just a random identifier which the server uses to map the request to a particular session object. As such, it isn't meant to be read from the client, so the cookie has the HttpOnly flag set. This is a good thing, because it prevents malicious script from hijacking your session.

Even if you could read the session cookie, it's just a meaningless ID. Values stored within the session will not be available from your script.

Comment: So, then, is there any way to make AJAX-style behavior with an ASP.NET project?

Comment: @JánosiZoltánJános You dont need to pass the SessionId when you do ajax in .Net. The server already knows who the ajax call is coming from. You can even access the session for that user from the serverside (although accessing session makes ajax calls synchronous unless the Session is marked as read only so it isnt recommended if it can be avoided). Check out this tutorial on ajax and asp.net http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/

Comment: @JoshMein Thx, I think it is a good start to redesign my HTML/jQuery code! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that I solved my original problem.
I just get the session ID from the URL, and then include it in the post URL.
I made a simple helper function where everything can be seen clearly:

```js
getSessionIDFromURL = function() 
{
  var sPathName = window.location.pathname;
  var urlRegex = "/(\\(S\\([a-z0-9]+\\)\\))/";
  var sSessionID = sPathName.match(urlRegex);
  return sSessionID[1];
}

var sBaseURLWithSessionID = "/" + getSessionIDFromURL() + "/";
```

Now my XHR request works with my ASP.NET sessions.